# Animating uiview continously using Core Graphics in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiview, core-graphics

I am creating a game like bubble shooter where the uiview object will animate continuously based on where a the screen is touched. I am able to animate my uiview object based on touch event but the problem is, it stops at a touch point where I clicked..I used uiview animation where i am giving 1 sec to animate the ball. But I don't want to stop the ball at that point and want it to automatically go to forward direction where i clicked and it should also take care of screen size that ball (UIView) does not go out of view.This is my code.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 gameTimer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateDisplay:)];
 [gameTimer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
-(void) updateDisplay:(CADisplayLink*)sender
{


                        if (lastTime == 0.0)
                        {
                           // First time through, initialize the lastTime
                             lastTime = previousTimeStampValue;


                         }
                         else
                         {

                             timeDelta = sender.timestamp - lastTime; // Update the lastTime
                             lastTime = sender.timestamp;


                             ballRect.origin.x += ballVelocity.x * timeDelta;
                             ballRect.origin.y += ballVelocity.y * timeDelta;

                             [self checkCollisionWithScreenEdges];
                        }

                   [currentBallView setFrame:ballRect];


                  // currentBallView.center = ballRect.origin;



}
```

Comment: Your velocity calculation is probably a little wrong, but I can't tell, since you didn't show the code. Then again, I wouldn't recommend using core graphics when you can use sprite kit.

Comment: I am using velocity(200,-200) to move my objects.